# My binary search function in c++ in Array is not working and I am not getting why

Tags: c++

My code isn't working. The problem may be in the loop.I was trying to write c++ code for Binary Search and it just doesn't execute.In computer science, binary search, also known as half-interval search, logarithmic search, or binary chop, is a search algorithm that finds the position of a target value within a sorted array. Binary search compares the target value to the middle element of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Array{
    int A[20];
    int length;
    int size;
};

int BinarySearch(struct Array arr,int key) {
    int low=0;
    int high=arr.length-1;
    int mid=(low+high)/2;
 
    while(low<=high) {
        if(key==arr.A[mid])
        return mid;
        
        else if(key<arr.A[mid])
        high=mid-1;
        
        else
        low=mid+1; 
    }    
    return -1; 
}

int main()
{
    struct Array arr={{2,3,7,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,79,90,91,111,112,334,556,778,990,999},20,20};
   cout<< BinarySearch(arr,7); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not adjust `mid` in the loop so it stays at the same index that you initialized it with.

Suggested change:

```
int BinarySearch(const Array& arr, int key) { // const&, no copy
    int low = 0;
    int high = arr.length - 1;
    int mid;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;    // assign mid inside the loop

        if (key < arr.A[mid])      // Put the less than and greater than ...
            high = mid - 1;
        else if(arr.A[mid] < key)  // ... comparisons first ...
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;            // ... and let equal be the last
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Putting the *less than* and *greater than* comparisons before the *equal* check is preferable for two reasons:

- Equal is usually going to be `false` so making the other comparisons first is often more effective.
- Equal comparisons don't work well with some types, like floating point types.